# Text based memory game | No clue how to make it restart

Tags: python, memory, text

Alright, so I'm using Python 3.4.3. I'm taking an entry level course for Python, and we're supposed to make a game. I've tried the search function for my problem but all of these answers are too confusing to me. I'm a Networking major so this is my first time ever messing around with code of any sort.

Basically, I'm making a text based memory game. There's 11 questions and they can type "y" for yes or anything else for no. When someone types in the wrong answer I want it to be so it goes back to the beginning of the game. I'm also trying to figure out how to add a way for the player to exit the game when they're finished besides just closing out of Python. I underestimated how difficult this would be for me and the project is due tonight at midnight (I'm cutting this pretty closely I know).

Here are the first few lines of my game:

```
# Game Introduction (Everything works, but it's unfinished and I still need to figure out how to restart the game when someone responds with the wrong question.)


print ('Welcome to The Dampest Dungeon. Try to stay alive!')

print (' ')

# When they first wake up.

print ('You awake in a damp dungeon. You see a door. Do you open the door?')
def dampest_dung():
   def function(y):
    return "y"
print ("testers")
game_resp = input('Type y for yes or n for no:')

print ('')

if game_resp=='y':
    print ("The door won't budge. You push harder and it falls on top of you. Game over.")
else:
    print ("Instead, you look under a rug and find a rusty key.")
print (' ')
# Second question where they can try the key.

print ('Will you try to use the rusty key on the door?')
gameresptwo = input('Type y for yes or n for no:')

print (' ')

if gameresptwo=='y':
    print ("The door opens noisily when you attempt to use the key.")
else:
    print ("You stand in the room without doing anything. Nothing happens. Eventually, you starve. Game over.")
```

You can see that there's only two options. If they choose the wrong one I want the game to restart. To say I'm a novice with Python or programming in general would be an understatement. I'm not trying to be fancy here. I'm looking for the simplest solution possible. Thank you very much!

I'm trying to define some functions so the game restarts but I can't get anything to work. Ughhh I'm so bad

Comment: There are a few ways of doing this. You could enclose everything in a while loop and `continue` when the user gets the question wrong

Comment: Please look into `for` and `while` loops.

Comment: Also, I can post the rest of my game if you guys like. I only showed the first two questions because they're all set up pretty much the same way but if anyone's curious I'll just share the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put your game into a function.

If you like the input you are receiving : you would be continuing to the end of your function, and in the end, if you like all the answers : it would return True.
If you dont like a single answer : the function would return False.

Then, you would have a loop encapsulating your function.
And, according to the output of your function (True or False) : you would either recompute your game, or end it.

I'm giving you an example as you tried something :

```
def my_game():
    ans_1 = input("My first question :"):
    if I_like_the_answer:
        print "You're good to go !"
    else:
        print "I'm sorry. You lose !"
        return False

    #   ...

    #   End of game.
    return True

#   Game is still not completed at this point.
my_game_results = False
while my_game_results is False:
    my_game_results = my_game()

print "You beat the game!"
```

Comment: Alright, so I hate to be annoying but does It matter where I put the function? Do I just put it at the start or does it not matter? Is there anyway you could give me a generic example or something because I'm a complete noob to this stuff and am confused by even the simplest terms.

Comment: I'm sorry and I'm probably going to make myself look even more foolish but I can't get it to work. I wish I could just message you privately because this stuff is probably just common sense to most people. This is what I tried:

Comment: You need to update your first post to show some code. I am here to provide help, but I won't give away a straight answer to a school problem. You need to work-out these problems in your head. You should learn the following concept : LOOP. A loop is a tool that will allow you to **do_things**, over and over again, until a condition is met.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to update the original question. I should have just made hangman or something because this is so over my head.

Comment: @Todd  I would look at how to define and call functions in python and while loops. That's all you need to know to do this. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

The way you've defined and called functions in your updated code is completely wrong